# How are hot meta posts selected?

Tags: support

This is a very small question with what will probably be a very quick answer.

The main scifi site has a right-hand sidebar with several meta questions listed, which change over time, and the hed "HOT META POSTS." What are the criteria for picking the posts to list, and is it driven by an algorithm, picked by a moderator, or selected in some other fashion?

I have no complaints; I'm just curious.

Comment: I wonder what happens if this very question becomes a "hot meta post".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They're selected by an algorithm :

> `(log(Qviews)*4) + ((Qanswers * Qscore)/5) + sum(Ascores)`
>   `--------------------------------------------------------`
>   `((QageInHours+1) - ((QageInHours - Qupdated)/2)) ^ 1.5`

[Original meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/4789/175002)

Comment: Fast work. Thanks!